# How to handle SQLiteOpenHelper and RoomDatabase in one app?

Tags: android, sql, migration, database-migration, android-room

I have huge DB, written with SQLiteOpenHelper. Now we are starting to implement Room to our project. So, my question is: how to be with migration problem?

For example, I have version number 100 in MySQLiteOpenHelper. I'm trying to migrate one table (and there are many other tables in DB) to Room.

I've create MIGRATION_100_101 in 
MyDatabase : RoomDatabase (@Database(version = 101) class. So, I need to increase version in MySQLiteOpenHelper to 101  and make sure, that MyDatabase with migrations will be called before MySQLiteOpenHelper?

Is there any other way to have both SQLiteOpenHelper and RoomDatabase in one app?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Room manages a separate database by itself and there isn't a great way to maintain a custom sqliteopenhelper and a room database. What we did was that we migrated subsets of the tables at once from old sqlite to room (basically, tables that need to be joined together for whatever reason), and kept two separate databases until all of the tables were migrated.

Depending on your situation, might be more painless to do a one-time migration for everything.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution, that allows us to do this is next. Let's imagine, that current DB version is X and we are planing to migrate to version X+1.

1. Create SQLiteOpenHelper object that will drop all tables, if the current DB version is X and recreates all NOT migrated tables for version X+1. We need to call `getReadableDatabase/getWritableDatabase` method so, table creation (methods onCreate/onUpgrade) takes place. This SQLiteOpenHelper object will be temporary.
2. Create RoomDatabase object for version X+2 with `fallbackToDestructiveMigration`. This will clear all migrated tables and recreates them. Also, we need to call `getReadableDatabase/getWritableDatabase` for creation take place. This RoomDatabase object is temporary too.
3. So, on this moment we have already created DB: part of the tables (that are not migrated) will be created by SQLiteOpenHelper, other - by RoomDatabase.
4. Create RoomDatabase object for version X+2 without `fallbackToDestructiveMigration`. And this object we are going to use in our application.
5. Create SQLiteOpenHelper object for version X+2, that will just use created DB (migration from X+1 to X+2 are not required at all, because tables was created by Room at step 2). And this object we are going to use in our application.